# Does Firefox developer edition support Legacy addon development now?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-developer-edition

It is mentioned that Legacy add-ons are deprecated([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions)). Though I am trying to make a very minor update to an existing add-on which is working fine on release channel.

I installed the add-on in the FF Developer Edition and found some issues:

1. `document.commandDispatcher.focusedWindow.getSelection().toString()`(to
   get the selected text) is not returning the selected value with no
   error.
2. The overlay window height and width is set using preferences but it seems to be not reading.

Comment: Yes, it is still supported. As to your example issues: You have two different examples, which might be more appropriate as two different questions.  You have not provided enough information to know what exactly the problem is for either of your two sub-questions/issue examples. For #1: A) we need a page and the text you have selected, etc. B) `getSelection()` is not sufficient to get the selected text in all circumstances. See [Retrieving a word that is selected](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28793200/3773011). For #2 you have provided no code. Without code debugging questions are off-topic.

Comment: @Makyen The question is if this is still supported. I have noticed some other issues too. I really appreciate your effort though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it works for the moment and will probably continue to do so for at least another year at the time of writing. But developer edition runs with e10s enabled, so your addon is probably facing e10s compatibility issues which will also [hit the release channel sooner](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis#Schedule) than discontinuation of those addon types.

As immediate workaround you can disable it in about:preferences, in the short term you will have to fix those issues, in the mid and long term you'll have to migrate to newer addon frameworks.

Comment: While e10s compatibility issues are a possible problem, we really don't have enough information to say one way or another. Checking if it is e10s/multi-process Firefox issues is easy by just disabling MP in `about:preferences` and do the problems go away. There are enough other possible issues with differences between release & beta vs developer/aurora/alpha that it really could be something else. For instance, one of my add-ons is non-functional in DE w/o e10s, but works fine in release and beta (even after fixing/changing the first three different non-function issues, still working on it).

Comment: @Makyen, the question was whether legacy (XUL) addons are still supported. Issues that may arise from using newer versions are separate from general support.